# Math ML MO uses

Tags: mathml, mo

What do following snippets of code do in Math ML files? I removed those lines and it still worked fine for me.

```
<mo>&#8289;</mo>
<mo>&#8290;</mo>
<mo>&#63449;</mo>
```

Answering to any of them or just letting me know what they are would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are [`&#8289;` function application](http://www.codetable.net/hex/2061) and  [`&#8290;` invisible times](http://www.codetable.net/hex/2062). They help indicate semantic information, see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Mathematical_invisibles)

The last one, [`&#63449;`](http://unicode-table.com/en/F7D9/), could be anything since it lies in the  [Unicode Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) which is provided so that font developers can store glyphs that do not correspond to regular Unicode positions. (Unless it's a typo and really [6349](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6349/index.htm) in which case it's a a Han character.)